# Ajax.BeginForm Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have a small problem with my ajax form binding. Here is some code:

my edit action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProductionArticle(Article article)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _ArticleRepository.Edit(article);
        return RedirectToAction("SelectArticle", new { id = article.DrawingNumber });
    }
    return PartialView(viewModel);
```

}

and here is my view:

```cs
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditProductionArticle", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "selectPartialArticle" }))
{
    <form class="nonActive disabled" id="form">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.productionArticle.DrawingNumber)

        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.productionArticle.ArticleDescr, "Article Description")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.productionArticle.ArticleDescr, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Article Description" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.productionArticle.ArticleDescr)

        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.sellTray, "Trays")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.productionArticle.SellTrayCode, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Trays" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.sellTray)

        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.productionArticle.BotCode, "Botanical Code")
        @Html.DropDownList("BotCode", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Botanical Code" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productionArticle.BotCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.productionArticle.CostGrpHL, "Cost Group HL")
        @Html.DropDownList("CostGrpHL", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Cost Group HL" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productionArticle.CostGrpHL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <input type="submit" value="EditProductionArticle" />
    </form>
}
```

My problem is the following: If i modify my edit action to look like this:

```cs
public ActionResult EditProductionArticle([Bind(Prefix = "productionArticle")]  Article article)
{ 
    //bla bla
}
```

it will bind everything but the dropdowns. If i don't, it will bind the dropdowns but nothing else. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Thx.

Comment: did you check the name of dropdown (in html) and attribute name (article class) are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use of `@Html.DropDownList("BotCode", null, ...)` means you creating a dropdownlist that is binding to a property named `BotCode` which does not exist in your model. You have not shown you model but based on the associated `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` it contains a property named `productionArticle` which is a complex object with a property named `BotCode`

Assuming your assigning the SelectLists to `ViewBag` properties in your GET method, give them a different name from the property your binding to, say

```cs
ViewBag.BotCodeList = new SelectList(...) // or new List<SelectListItem>...
```

and then in the view use the strongly typed helpers to bind to your model property

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.productionArticle.BotCode, (SelectList)ViewBag.BotCodeList, ...)
```

or `...(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BotCodeList`

Comment: but then i keep getting this: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'productionArticle.BotCode'.

Comment: That's because your returning the view in the POST method (I assume because `ModelState` is not valid) and not reassigning the value of `ViewBag.BotCodeList` before you return the view

Comment: In addition your first code snippet shows a POST method with parameter `Article article`but then you have `return View(viewModel);` but I assume that's just a typo?

Comment: Well, the thing is i don't get to call that Edit action now. I get the error as soon as i start debugging. About the returning of that view, that is if the ModelState isn't valid. Otherwise i am redirecting to another action.

Comment: `viewModel` does not even exist in that POST method so that would throw an error for a start. You need to show your model and the GET method so I can work out what your really trying to do!

Comment: And why do you have `return RedirectToAction()` in the `EditProductionArticle()` method. Your view has `Ajax.BeginForm()` which means its making an ajax call which means you stay on the same page (ajax calls do not redirect)

Comment: about the redirect, I forgot about it, i started with a Html.BeginForm and switched to Ajax after that

Comment: @Spluf, In comments, you put code inside backticks [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: It's actually working. I forgot to modify something inside my ViewBag and i was getting that code from the wrong place. Thanks a lot for the answer.. the final code for the dropedown is -----------------------> `@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.productionArticle.BotCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BotCodeList, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Botanical Code" })` (p.s., thx a lot, you were extremely helpful)